# How to convert csv into database table

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

Is there a way to import a csv into a SQL table, without having a previously-constructed table? I know how to import a csv into an existing table, but is there a way to create one from the csv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using phpMyAdmin ,
(in this method csv file first row elements use as column names for the sql table)
1) select database
2) go to import tab and select csv file
3) ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ [image: import options]
4) after above steps new table will be created and if you want to change table names instead of having table1,table2
select table and go to operation tab :)

(phpMyAdmin 4.1.14)

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert in MySQL but I don't believe there is such an import process. And there might not be in other database servers like [Oracle](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ#What_is_SQL.2ALoader_and_what_is_it_used_for.3F), [SQL Server](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/), or [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html). In fact, it may not be a desirable automation as a table should be user defined and created to fit the database's relational model and for appropriate data types, indices, and keys.

Almost all SQL dialects require setting up the database table beforehand. If not, how would the system know beforehand you intended an integer or long number, a double or decimal number, a  tinytext or longtext, which fields are to be indexed, or serve as primary key, and so on?

You might argue [MS Access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835958.aspx) allows a CSV import with an optional table name. However, the ribbon wizard walks the user through setting up the field types, primary key, and table name. And going the non-wizard automation route, the `DoCmd.TransferText` method requires table name when using the `acImportDelim` argument.

So, your best process in [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) may be `LOAD DATA INFILE` to run a bulk import of an external CSV into an existing table.